# Adding startup file for an Azure function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I saw there's an option to add a startup file to a function app as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection). I want to add one mainly for DI.

For now, everything works without having a startup file. If that's the case, how do I know what I should actually configure there? Logically for me, it sounds like it should work even if it remains empty since it doesn't exist now, but maybe if it does exist, I need to add dependencies manually by code which were added automatically before?

My csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">


<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityModel" Version="5.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.9">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="RT.Comb" Version="2.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="SharpZipLib" Version="1.3.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Migrations\" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

***Function Code***

```cs
[FunctionName("MyFunc")] 
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run( [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
```

Comment: What is the framework and version of your Function App ?

Comment: Please share your `.csproj` file.

Comment: @Harshitha I've edited the question with the csproj file

Comment: And also share your `Programe.cs` file.

Comment: @Harshitha I don't have a program.cs file for the app function. I only got the business logic with an entry point of a method defined like this (sorry but im not sure how to format comments): 

[FunctionName("MyFunc")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log) ...

Comment: Add the Function code in the question itself.Edit the code which I ahev added in the post.

Comment: Have you tried to add Startup.cs file in the application root directory?

Comment: No. The tutorial says I need to install some nugets before that.. and even then, the main question still remains - what do I need to add in the start up file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255107/discussion-between-harshitha-and-codemonkey).

Answer (score 0):

From your `.csproj` it is clear that your app is Configured with `Azure Function.NET 6 (LTS)`.

> Adding startup file for an Azure function app.
> I want to add one mainly for DI.

Add a new file with name `Startup.cs` in the root directory of the Function App.

> The tutorial says I need to install some nugets before that.

- By default, `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` NuGet package is installed when we Create a Function App (you can check in `.csproj` file.

To run the Startup file, we need to add the assembly attribute as mentioned in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#register-services), without this the Startup file won't get Initialized and triggered.

```cs
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(YourNameSpace.Startup))]
```

- I have tried to add the same, you can see the namespace is missing.

[image]

- Click on the Show potential fixes, it suggests you to Install related packages.
  [image]
- Even if you are not adding any logic in the Startup file for now and want to make it ready for future purpose, you need to add the `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions` package (to add the assembly attribute) and refer `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;` in using namespaces.

[image]

- If you want to add any other middleware logic like `AddSingleton`, then you need to install and add refer `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` package.

***Format of Default `Startup.cs` without any logic:***

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(FunctionDI.Startup))]
namespace FunctionDI
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And I don't need to add any services/dependencies for it to work the same as it now?

Comment: If you dont want to add any logic and still you need Startup.cs file, you can add the above code and continue with your Default Functions.

Comment: Place a break point in `Startup.cs` file you can check that it is triggered. [Image](https://i.imgur.com/CNIAMiK.png)

Comment: I still havn't tested it. When doing so, I will accept if everything works